# How to handle memory error in large excel files

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

#my task is read this file file create a pivot table so while reading the file on the basis of column name i am getting a meemmory error is there is way to handle it

```
import os
    import xlrd
    import pandas as pd
    import openpyxl as xl
    ##get current directory
    cwd= os.getcwd()
    print("This script is to update")
    print("Starting to populate the Data Validation File")
    filename_1 =[os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk(os.getcwd())
                           for f in files
                           if f.startswith('1') and f.endswith('.xlsx')]
    filename_1=filename_1[0]

    book_1 = xl.load_workbook(filename_1)
    ws = book_1["J"]
    print("Loaded the filename:")
    for filename in os.listdir(cwd):
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx') and filename.startswith(('Seeep_')):
            book = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
            for sheet in book.sheet_names:
   here i am i am getting the memory error how to handle this the file is really big**


    df = book.parse(sheet)
                if 'comp' in df.columns:
                    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
                    df['comp1']=df['com']
                    print("For "+filename+"\n"+" Creating the Pivot Table")
                    book2=df[(df.Iy!='SE')].pivot_table(values='comp',index=['os','sv'], columns='comp', aggfunc='count',margins=True)
                    print(book2)
                    book3=df.pivot_table(values='compl',index=['Ring','os','sv'], columns='comp', aggfunc='count',margins=True)
```

Comment: any help in this still struggling

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. Converting the Excel sheets to individual CSVs. E.g. use https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html#read-only-mode to iterate over rows and write them to CSV using Python's CSV writing API https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer
2. Then use Pandas to load CSVs, making sure to load only the columns you really need, and to set column types to use less memory. https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-load-less-data/ covers how to do this.

Comment: No need to go through CSV: create dataframes directly in read-only mode.

Comment: Creating dataframes directly might still use too much memory. But yes, that might be an option.

Comment: Going via CSV here really isn't necessary, there's nothing you can do with it that the read-only mode won't let you do.